# Roku Developer: MP4 streaming optimization question(s)

Tags: mp4, roku

We're new to video, but are tasked with building a Roku Channel which will allow the user to view existing MP4/MOV files. They are being stored on Azure cloud storage with an CDN.

The MP4's are made with an AVC1 codec, and video content type of video/H264.

A few questions:

- Is there anything we need to do on the cloud storage provider to ensure streaming is working?
- It seems like Roku might be downloading the entire video prior to playing, is that expected behavior for this file type?
- Should we convert these to some other file format? The Roku developer documents simply list out the supported types, and MP4 is one, but are some preferencial to others?

I realize this is somewhat open ended, but if anyone else has any tips it would be very helpful.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

MP4 is supported in roku but using hls or dash is better approach than playing MP4, because it give smooth video playing.
Roku do not download mp4 video. Maybe there is some issue with your videos.

```js
 m.videoContent = CreateObject("RoSGNode", "ContentNode")
            m.videoContent.url = << Your video id>>
            m.videoContent.content = << your video url>>
            m.videoContent.streamFormat = "mp4"
            m.videoPlayer.control = "play"
```

you just have to simply do this to play a mp4 video.